# modulo error on matrix operation

Tags: c++, encryption, modulo

So I'm trying to calculate the inverse of a matrix using the determinate. My loop gets no errors when I remove the `% 26` but when I include it I get the following errors:

> '=' : conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data
>   illegal, left operand has type 'float'

Any help on how I can get around this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        if (adjacency_matrix[i][j] < 0)
            adjacency_matrix[i][j] = (adjacency_matrix[i][j] * 17) % 26;
        else
            for (float x = 0; x < 50; x++){
                if (x * -26 < adjacency_matrix[i][j])
                    adjacency_matrix[i][j] = adjacency_matrix[i][j] + x * 26;
            }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry..I'm new to the site, the etiquette escapes me sometimes.  It's c++ and the matrix is float, its just regular numbers. Integers, i used float just in case but I don't believe any of them work out to be decimals.

Answer (score 0):

The modulo operator `%` works only for integers. C++11 ([N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)) 5.6 - 2 (emphasis mine):

> The operands of * and / shall have arithmetic or unscoped enumeration type; **the operands of % shall have integral** or unscoped enumeration **type**. **The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands and determine the type of the result.**

Float values will be converted to integer values which *might* result in reduction in precision (losing the fractional part). Whether there is indeed a reduction, is not checked by the compiler on a case by case basis. It rightly reports that such a reduction is possible.

If you only have integers in your `adjacency_matrix`, then use one of the many integer types instead of float. If you really may have genuine float values, then you can use [fmod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/).